# Format text file using python

Tags: python, regex

I have a raw text something like below:

> 0000001AB111172323235-8THis is the
>   description.00000323CD41111944322Soft Dimcase
>   andRating00000033322S112212234-3100 BN SN OPTION
>   (LINUX)000022664422444433AVaaaaaccaaaaaaa

And i am trying to convert it like below:

```
0000001AB11117, 2323235-8,  This is the description.
00000323CD4111, 1944322,    Soft Dimcase andRating
00000033322S11, 2212234-3,  100 BN SN OPTION (LINUX)
00000226644224, 44433AV,    aaaaaccaaaaaaa
```

The rule above is to take 14 characters (could be mix of letters and numbers) and then insert ", " then take next 7 characters (could be mix of letters and numbers) and if next character is "-" then include hyphen and immediate digit and then insert ", " and then read out all the description until we find three consecutive 000. Once three consecutive 0's are found then i need to insert new line before 000 and then repeat the same process so that i can make it formatted. Basically i want to read out all column values. Please suggest what could be done.

I tried below but in this i need to hard code value in order to insert ", " or '\n' but here i am hard coding and not sure how to make it dynamic.

```
def format_file(filename, find, insert):
    with open(page2, 'r+') as file:
        lines = file.read()

        index = repr(lines).find(find) - 1
        if index < 0:
            raise ValueError("The text was not found.")

        len_found = len(find) - 1
        existing_lines = lines[index + len_found:]

        file.seek(index)
        file.write(find)
        file.write(insert)
        file.write(existing_lines)

format_file(page2, "0000001AB11117", ', ')
format_file(page2, "2323235-8", ', ')
format_file(page2, "This is the description.", '\n')
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case you can parse file text by regexp.

- `The rule above is to take 14 characters (could be mix of letters and numbers)` - `[a-zA-Z\d]{14}`
- `then take next 7 characters (could be mix of letters and numbers) and if next character is "-" then include hyphen and immediate digit and then insert "` - `[\da-ZA-Z]{7}(\-\d)?`
- `and then read out all the description until we find three consecutive 000` - `.+?(?=(000|$))`

Please, check this one:

```
import re

expr = re.compile(r'(?P<first>[\da-zA-Z]{14})(?P<second>[\da-ZA-Z]{7}(\-\d)?)(?P<third>.+?(?=(000|$)))')

text = '''0000001AB111172323235-8THis is the description.00000323CD41111944322Soft Dimcase andRating00000033322S112212234-3100 BN SN OPTION (LINUX)000022664422444433AVaaaaaccaaaaaaa'''

for m in expr.finditer(text):
    print "{}, {}, {}\n".format(m.group('first'), m.group('second'), m.group('third'))
```

Output:

```
0000001AB11117, 2323235-8, THis is the description.

00000323CD4111, 1944322, Soft Dimcase andRating

00000033322S11, 2212234-3, 100 BN SN OPTION (LINUX)

00002266442244, 4433AVa, aaaaccaaaaaaa
```

Comment: @Shpionus This is really great. It works as expected when i assign all text to `text` variable, but when i am trying to read directly from the file, it is not printing anything, probably because it is reading 1 letter at a time. Please suggest.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I implemented rules described in question. Regular expression match desired pattern. Then I just `print` in requested format.

Comment: I tried with `open(page2, 'r') as f:
    for m in expr.finditer(f):` but then i am getting **TypeError: expected string or buffer** so basically i am not able to read from file.

Comment: @ankitpandey You read file line by line. But my script works with full text. I not sure how looks your file. If file not big, you can totally read it to variable and use this code. If file big enough, need find some other iterative way.

Comment: @ankitpandey `expr.finditer` works with string variable, not file description.

Comment: @Shpionus my file is not more than 1 page of text file.

Comment: I am not claiming that your code is wrong. I am saying that you should write your answer with the assumption that the information you are presenting is completely new to OP. For example, I suspect that there is a very good chance that OP is completely unfamiliar with regexes. While it is certainly not your job to explain regex from scratch, a bit of prose explaining what your regex means with some level of detail would help not only OP, but future visitors to the site as well.

Comment: `open(page2, 'r') as f: for m in expr.finditer(f.read()):` worked. Thanks @Shpionus

Comment: @MadPhysicist OK, I just thought that regexp pretty common thing and no need to explain

Comment: I added some more explanation

Comment: This question would likely not have been posted if OP thought so. There was a time when we all didn't know about the common stuff. The purpose of SO is to help us through those times by teaching the general method as well as the specific details.

Comment: I flipped my vote to up. Thanks for listening. For what it's worth I think you turned this into a very good answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `re` regular expression module is a good way of parsing simple text structures. In your case the trick is breaking the stream into records when you hit the next `000`. Itteratively processing the string with the look ahead pattern `(?=000)` will match your separators. We use the look ahead as you also want to leave this as part of the following record. We also want to terminate a record on end of file hence the alternative `$` pattern. The rest of the pattern is just breaking out the fields.

```
re_line = re.compile(r'(.{14})(.{7})(-\d|)(.*?)((?=000)|$)')

with open(page2, 'r') as f:
    for m in re_line.finditer(f.read()):
        print '{0}, {1}{2}, {3}'.format(*m.groups())
```

outputs:

```
0000001AB11117, 2323235-8, THis is the description.
00000323CD4111, 1944322, Soft Dimcase andRating
00000033322S11, 2212234-3, 100 BN SN OPTION (LINUX)
00002266442244, 4433AVa, aaaaccaaaaaaa
```

Comment: @Mike From where `a` came into picture ? When  i replace `a` with `f` i am getting **TypeError: expected string or buffer** error

Comment: @ankitpandey that should have been `f.read()` I'll correct code. Sorry, I was rushing.